EF Core 8, null check in query removed during translation
context.Table
       .Where(d => d.col1 == null || d.col1 == value1)
                && d.Active == true)

DbQuery generated removes d.col1 == null and only uses d.col1 = 'value1'.
Not sure if missing anything with EF Core 8.
Expecting query should use
d.col1 = null OR d.col1 = value1


Instead of d.col1 == null, does !d.col1.HasValue work?  If not, what data type is col1?  Specifically, is it a nullable type?

Let me try and see if it works. and yes col1 is definitely null and I do need to check for it, considering, that's how data is set

I followed your suggestion and can confirm now that the model had property defined as "public string col1 {get;set;}".  After changing it to "public string? col1 {get;set;}" it worked. So, it was my issue

What are the actual types? A non-nullable property can't be null.

Putting it here, to help others.
The issue was not with EF Core 8, but, with how my model was.
Earlier Property:
public string Col1 {get; set;}
So, when I ran query:
context.Table.Where(d => d.col1 == null || d.col1 == value1) && d.Active == true)
it generated:
t.col1 == 'values1'.
This used to work in old EF Core 3, while I think, it has changed and now, I have to specify the nullable field specifically in my model. I feel this is a welcome change, even though I got bitten by it.
After Property:
public string? Col1 {get; set;} works.
DB Query:
t.col1 == 'value1' OR t.col1 IS NULL

EF Core 8 respects nullability both when mapping and querying, so  nonnull == null gets eliminated. If you try to load data that has null in a non-nullable property you'll get an error. That's how most people (including me) discovered this - a query failed when they tried to load a NULL in a non-nullable property

ASP.NET Core also respects nullability and will reject a POST as a Bad Request if a non-nullable property is missing. Something most of us also found out the hard way
